# Excel custom date format not showing in formula bar and pivot table

Tags: excel, vba

I’m trying to override the date format of cells that is 01/10/2018 to Jan/10/2018 in a sheet that is the pivot table source. In the cells, it shows Jan/10/2018, but in the formula bar it shows 01/10/2018.

In the pivot table it also shows 01/10/2018 even when overriding it with a macro.

I tried using an apostrophe in front of the Jan/10/2018 but then I get a 46772 number in the cell.

Any ideas? Please help!

One problem: The data is cleaned on opening in VBS so I cannot use a formula manually

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Format_Date ()

Selection.NumberFormat = "mmm-dd-yyyy"

End Sub
```

Try applying this code to your date and it should do the work.

Comment: I tried this with Range but it didn’t work, because I can’t do selection (it’s an automated workbook through VBA)

Comment: So, you cannot change the way the Formula bar looks as it is based on your computers clock setting : Short date. If you are willing to change your computers setting and make the following changes you require I can post another answer to this.

Comment: Yes, I’m willing to make the changes. Most important is that the pivot table shows Jan/10/2018 and not what’s in the formula bar

Answer (score 0):

In the Formula Bar, a date will show according to your computer's setting for the "Short date".

In Control Panel > Clock, Language and Region > Region and Language you can set these defaults for your computer.

The Excel "short date" format will always be displayed in the formula bar. In the screenshot below, you can see my regional settings. The Excel cell has today's date, formatted as a "Long Date". The formula bar shows the "Short date", which is determined by the computer's regional settings.

So, no, you cannot change the way the date shows in the formula bar, unless you are prepared to change your computer settings for "short date". This will then apply to all applications that use that date format, which may be way more than just Excel.

[image: Follow this link for picture example]

Comment: Ok, that’s fair. The question is, how can I ensure that the pivot table doesn’t use the short date, but rather my custom date on opening of the workbook?

Comment: So Basically you want JAN-10-2018 to show on Pivot table as well but it doesn't show?

Comment: Yes, but with slash, so Jan/10/2018. Because I’m 100% sure the pivot table uses the short date that’s in the formula bar and not the cell value Jan/10/2018

Comment: @MJ95 you can change the format of the data in the pivot table just like normal cells.

Comment: I did that, but the pivot table is only filled upon workbook open and then it defaults back to 01/10/2018

Comment: Then add code to the opening code that populates the pivot table to change the format to the desired output.

Comment: @Scott Craner It doesn’t override the underlying short date of the cells, so when I copy it to the pivot table it doesn’t work